# SQLAlchemy relationship: list of objects matching either of two ForeignKey columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have two tables in my database, one for Matches and one for Teams. The Match has columns that store the id of the teams playing.

```py
class Match(Base):
    id_ = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True, primary_key=True)
    team1_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('teams.id')
    team2_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('teams.id')

class Team(Base):
    id_ = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True, primary_key=True)
```

**I would like to create a relationship between the two tables such that:**

- **`Match.teams` returns a list of two `Team` objects, containing the teams with ids that match `team1_id` or `team2_id`**
- **`Team.matches` returns a list of `Match` objects, containing all the matches where this team's id is present in either the `team1_id` or `team2_id` columns**

From a SQL perspective, I don't need another table - all of the relationship information is present in the tables as stated above. However, does SQLAlchemy require an association table for this to work?

*Attempt 1*:

```py
class Match(Base):
    ...
    teams = relationship('Team', back_populates='matches', lazy='selectin',
                         foreign_keys=[team1_id, team2_id])

class Team(Base):
    ...
    matches = relationship('Match', back_populates='teams', lazy='selectin')
```

Resulted in the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Match.teams - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.
Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

Which confused me as I thought that that was what I was doing! What did I do wrong?

*Attempt 2*:

```py
class Match(Base):
    ...
    teams = relationship('Team',
                         back_populates='matches',
                         lazy='selectin',
                         primaryjoin=('or_(Team.id==Match.team1_id,'
                                          'Team.id==Match.team2_id)'))


class Team(Base):
    ...
    matches = relationship('Match', back_populates='teams', lazy='selectin')
```

This resulted in `Match.teams` returning a single value of the first team with an id that matched `team1_id` or `team2_id`.

**Is what I want to do possible? How should it be done? Is it possible to do without creating another table in the database?**

Answer (score 1):

You could use a property to do this, which might be easier to read:

```
class Match(Base):
    ...
    @property
    def teams(self) -> Tuple[Team, Team]:
        return session.get(Team, self.team1_id), session.get(Team, self.team2_id)
```

You'd use it just like any other attribute: `match.teams` is a tuple of Team objects.

Comment: Given that this is an option, why do sqlalchemy `relationship`s exist? What's the perceived advantage?

Comment: Note that this won't work with async databases

Comment: The `relationship` is simple and easy for the usual case: this field relates to that field. It gives you an English description, and SQLAlchemy does the queries for you. The example in the question is definitely an unusual case, so I'm not surprised it's not supported out of the box.